# Flexbox space-between with even item distribution

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to archive even space between flexbox items, but the justify-content: space-between does not seem to work as I expected.
I need each item to have a width of 4px.
I know I can use justify-content:space-evenly, but then the first and last item are not and the start/end of the box.
I also tried setting margin-right: auto on the items, but it does not work either.
There have to be 40 items.
Do you know any other solution to this?

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}
.item{
     width: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
                
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/marcin-sieradzki/pen/XWjGKYx

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Do you mean that 4px blue space has to place from start to end of the container?

Comment: What means: *"are not and the "* ? *"There have to be 40 items"* ...there are?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use margin-left .item

```
.item {
      margin-left: 5px;
 }
```

Example:

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  width: 4px;
  margin-left: 5px;     /* add this */
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added a Runnable snippet of your suggestion 

Comment: is that ironic?

Comment: No, it's just an emoji looking at the runnable snippet